# What features do I have to activate to get Content search web part (CSWP)

Tags: feature, content-search-web-part, cswp

I thought that by enabling:

- SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure (Site collection feature)
- SharePoint Server Standard Site features (Site feature)

I would get the content search web part, but what do I miss?

[image]

Comment: What version of SharePoint do you have? Foundation or Enterprise?

Comment: You need enterprise for this webpart

Comment: If you have Enterprise enabled and still no webpart, check this: http://www.maadarani.com/missing-content-search-web-part/

Comment: Do you have `Cross-Site Collection Publishing` site collection feature activated?

Comment: @Plexus81 this was a ["one more thing to try"](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/225073) besides the already asked (which were the first things to check first). I was also about to add that the two features you mentioned could be de- & re-activated if that would've been possible in your environment, but wanted to see your answer to the first questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This webpart requires Enterprise features to be enabled in your environment. If this is not enabled the webpart will not be available.

[Here's a guide](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-enable-enterprise-features-in-sharepoint-2013-central-administration/) on how to do that

If you still have problems after that [check this link](http://www.maadarani.com/missing-content-search-web-part/) for another possible cause

Comment: Just to clarify: What is meant is the *SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features* on site collection level. Not on site level.

Comment: The link which is mentoned in the answer is not working. Please correct. http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2013/10/sharepoint-enterprise-feature-activation-unintended-consequences/

Answer (score 1):

If your Microsoft subscription is not E3, E5, or SharePoint Online 2, you do not have access Content Search Web Part. But you can ask Microsoft for it here: https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/264636-general/suggestions/18776182-make-the-content-search-webpart-cswp-available-t

Answer (score -1):

It requires SharePoint 2013 Enterprise version to have those web parts available.